# How can you make this view in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, view, slide

[please click here to see which view I have to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pI1F0.png)

I have to make a map view which is similar to apple maps, and it has description view on top of the map view. The user can slide the description view left and right to see the route description in order.

I have no idea what these are called or how these are made. I really want to google but have no idea which keyword I have to use.

Please Help!

Comment: Hint: PageViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pagerview, you can use this library [FSPagerView](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSPagerView). Or, you can do it yourself by using scrollview or collectionview. Implement the scrollViewDidScroll to detect what is the current page and show the correct view

Answer (score 0):

To make that view shown in picture, all you need to do is

- take a UICollectionView and put it on your mapview. Provide UICollectionView a constraints at top, leading and trailing. Also you need yo provide height constraint of about 120-150.
- in your ViewController drag and make an outlet of this UICollectionView.
- Make your UIViewController follow UICollectionViewDelegate and UICollectionViewDataSource.
- create a UICollectionViewCell with a xib file.
- register that cell in your UIViewController.
- create a datamodel which has properties that you need in order to show the direction data.
- create an array in that UIViewController.
- use that array as a data source of UICollectionView.

Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, UIPageViewController works well:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    var mapView: MKMapView!
    var data: [String] = {
        var data = [String]()
        for _ in 0...5 {
            data.append("덕원 아파트에서 출발합니다.")
        }
        return data
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView = MKMapView()
        self.view.addSubview(mapView)
        mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // pageVC setup
        let cardVC = CardViewController(data: data[0])
        let pageVC = PageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
        pageVC.setViewControllers([cardVC], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
        pageVC.dataSource = self
        
        // container view for containment
        let containerView = UIView()
        view.addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.backgroundColor = .black
        
        // containment
        addChild(pageVC)
        containerView.addSubview(pageVC.view)
        pageVC.didMove(toParent: self)
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        pageVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // mapView
            mapView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
            mapView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor),
            
            // container view
            containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8),
            containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2),
            
            // pageVC
            pageVC.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.widthAnchor),
            pageVC.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.heightAnchor)
        ])
        
        let pageControl = UIPageControl.appearance()
        pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
        pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .white
        pageControl.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let info = (viewController as! CardViewController).label.text, var index = data.firstIndex(of: info)  else { return nil }
        index += 1
        if index > data.count {
            return nil
        }
        return CardViewController(data: data[index])
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let info = (viewController as! CardViewController).label.text, var index = data.firstIndex(of: info) else { return nil }
        index -= 1
        if index <= 0 {
            return nil
        }
        return CardViewController(data: data[index])
    }
    
    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        let pageVC = pageViewController.viewControllers![0] as! CardViewController
        let t = pageVC.label.text!
        return data.firstIndex(of: t)!
    }
}

class PageViewController: UIPageViewController {
    
}

class CardViewController: UIViewController {
    var label: UILabel!
    var containerView: UIView!
    var iconView: IconView!
    
    init(data: String) {
        self.label = UILabel()
        self.label.text = data
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func loadView() {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .black
        view = v
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        containerView = UIView()
        view.addSubview(containerView)
        
        // container view
        containerView.addSubview(label)
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // label
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.backgroundColor = .black
        label.textColor = .white
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        
        // icon view
        iconView = IconView()
        containerView.addSubview(iconView)
        iconView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // containerView
            containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor),
            containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
            
            // icon view
            iconView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.4),
            iconView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.heightAnchor),
            iconView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            
            // label
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconView.trailingAnchor),
            label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.heightAnchor),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
        ])
        
    }
}

class IconView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let circle = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: self.center, radius: 20, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * .pi, clockwise: true)
        UIColor.orange.setFill()
        circle.fill()
    }
}
```

[image]